# Exception: Element type is invalid: expected a string in react-native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When I try to run navigation I receive an error:

> Exception: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `Navigator`.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';

import App from './app/App'

export default class MyApp extends Component {

  renderScene (route, navigator) {
      if (route.name === 'App') {
        return <App navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />
      }
  }

  configureScene (route) {
    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Navigator
        configureScene={ this.configureScene.bind(this) }
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}
        initialRoute={{ name: 'App' }}
        renderScene={ this.renderScene.bind(this) }
      />
    )
  }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: The `renderScene` method needs to always return a valid view. In your case, you only return a view for the "App" route.

Comment: Sorry @jevakallio, I don't understand you.

Answer (score 1):

You should import your App component like this:

```
import { App } from './app/App'
```